# Is there a way to record the changes of one model in another?

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way to record the changes of one model in another? Let me explain, I need my **InventoryMovement model** to save the date and quantity of the new stock that enters my **Product model**.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    barcode = models.CharField('Barcode', max_length=13, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField('Name product', max_length=60)
    price_cost = models.DecimalField('Cost price', max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    price_sale = models.DecimalField('Sale price', max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField('Stock', default=0)

class InventoryMovement(models.Model):
    update_date = models.DateTimeField('Datetime')
    barcode_product = models.CharField('Barcode', max_length=13, unique=True)
    new_stock = models.PositiveIntegerField('Stock', default=0)
```

I am new in this world of programming and I am not sure how to do it and if it is possible

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout signals in django. There you can track actions on model instances: when they are created, modified deleted. Specifically refer to post_save, pre_save etc. because there are also signals for other actions.

[django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/)

If I understood you correctly, you can do some operations with InventoryMovements, in signal handlers of model Products.

Comment: Also naming convention of django recommends model namings not in plural form. e.i Product is better option)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Use pre_save () method to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

what I did was the following

```
def product_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        # Getting previous stock
        stock_previous = Product.objects.get(barcode=instance.barcode)
        stock_previous.stock = str(stock_previous.stock)
        stock_previous = int(stock_previous.stock)

        # Getting new stock
        stock_new = instance.stock
        stock_new = int(stock_new)

        # Updated stock
        stock_updated = stock_new - stock_previous

        movs = InventoryMovement.objects.create(
            barcode=instance.barcode,
            new_stock=stock_updated,
            update_date=timezone.now()
        )
        movs.save()
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        print("Product does not exist")
    else:
        pass

pre_save.connect(InventoryMovement, sender=Product)
```